# Python storing & accessing information via txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a gambling/dice game program for a course I'm taking, each week new requirements are added, and we have to implement the new code w/o radically changing the code we have written thus far. The part I'm having trouble with is: right now, if the user quits (by entering "0" as their "bet"), the contents of their "bank" is saved to a text file, so they can resume play later with the same amount of "winnings". If the user goes bankrupt (game over), the next time they run the program their bank is reset to the default amount ($500). When the program starts, the code is supposed to check to see if a file holding previous play data (bank.txt) exists; if the file exists, the number in bank.txt is the user's "bank"; if the file doesn't exist, the program creates it and adds $500 to the user's bank. By tweaking things here and there I've gotten *parts* of the code to work (i.e., quit with $800 in bank, restart game and it's still there), but I've been at it so long (and am so frustrated) I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
> `import os
import random
def main():
    intro()
    bank = check_bank()
    show_bank(bank)
    bet = bet_validation(bank)`
```

That's the beginning of the program, obviously, the part I can't seem to get right is below... If I need to post more of the code, that's not a problem, it's just that everything else seems to work right (except for the following)

```
def check_bank():
    try:
        if os.path.isfile('./bank.txt') == True:
            bank_file = open('bank.txt','r')
            if float(bank_file.readline()) > 0.0:
                bank = float(bank_file.readline())
                return bank
            else:
                bank = 500.00
                return bank
        else:
            bank_file = open('bank.txt','w')
            bank_file.write(str(500.0))
            bank = float(bank_file.readline())
            bank_file.close()
            return bank
    except IOError:
        print('IOError in check_bank')
    except ValueError:
        print('ValueError in check_bank')
    except Exception as err:
        print(err,'in check_bank')
    finally:
        bank_file.close()
```

Any and all help/suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated. When I start the program, I get a "ValueError" exception from the "check_bank()" function. I'd be happy to provide the rest of my code, if necessary, just included this bit because it seems to be where I'm having the problem. If you can help, *please* let me know what I'm doing wrong, and how to correct it! Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Can you replace `except ValueError` to `except ValueError as e` and then `print(e)`? Or just show a stack trace? Also you mixed up your `else` branch.

Comment: "Could not convert string to float"... The "string" in question is "500.0"

Comment: try to save that string into object and print it also to be sure that it doesn't contain wrong characters. Cause `float('500.0')` will work in 100% of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @deHart mentions, the exception is "Could not convert string to float". The problem is that you are reading the first line to check the text file, and then reading the next (empty) line to set the bank.

Instead, read the line and store to a variable. Then, do the comparison and set the bank from this variable - that should fix the ValueError.

Here is the modified version that worked for me:

```
def check_bank():
    try:
        if os.path.isfile('./bank.txt') == True:
            bank_file = open('bank.txt','r')
            vault = float(bank_file.readline())
            if vault > 0.0:
                bank = vault
                return bank
            else:
                bank = 500.00
                return bank
        else:
            bank_file = open('bank.txt','w')
            bank_file.write(str(500.0))
            bank = float(bank_file.readline())
            bank_file.close()
            return bank
    except IOError:
        print('IOError in check_bank')
    except ValueError:
        print('ValueError in check_bank')
    except Exception as err:
        print(err,'in check_bank')
    finally:
        bank_file.close()
```

A few notes here:

- This 'fixes' the problem, but you could still throw a ValueError.
- This may be covered elsewhere, but you'll want to update the text file when the bank drops below 0!

Comment: Good job! You beat me to the answer by approximately 12 minutes! I was having a *real* hard time. There is code present to keep bank from dipping below 0 (game over once bank hits 0, input validation to keep player from betting more than they have in bank). I really, really appreciate that you took the time to help me out man!

Answer (score 1):

Finally cracked it! Changed the following code around, and bingo!

```
def check_bank():
try:
    if os.path.isfile('./bank.txt') == True:
        bank_file = open('bank.txt','r')
        bank = float(bank_file.readline())
        if bank > 0:
            return bank
        else:
            bank = 500.0
            return bank
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store your values in plain text. I prefer using pickle

```
import pickle, os

def check_bank():
    try:
        file_path = './bank.txt'

        #ckeck if file exists
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            file_handler = open(file_path,'rb')
            bank = pickle.load(file_handler)

            return bank

        #if the file doesn't exist    
        else:
            file_handler = open(file_path, 'wb')
            pickle.dump(500, file_handler)
            file_handler.close()
            return 500
    except IOError:
        print("IOError occured")

    except EOFError:
        #if the file is empty
        file_handler = open(file_path, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(500, file_handler)
        file_handler.close()
        return 500
```

Comment: Still being rather new, this answer is a bit beyond me... But I am intrigued. I will definitely be looking into what you've shown me here, and hopefully learn all I can from it.